# Unhandled exceptions - forcing program exit

Tags: c++, exception, unhandled-exception

I have the following example:

```
void Unhandled() {
    cout << "Unhandled exception!" << endl;
//  exit(-1);
}
int main(){
    float a, b;
    set_terminate(Unhandled);

    try{
        cout << "Input two numbers: ";
        cin >> a >> b;
        if (b == 0)
            throw "Division by zero!";
        cout << a / b;
    }
    catch (int n){
        cout << "Error ID: " << n << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code that handles 'unhandled' exceptions but it still forces me to exit the program with 'exit' function or it calls 'abort' by default. Can this be avoided so that I continue executing the application normally after 'Unhandled' is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

impossible - when `Unhandled` is called, your program has already crashed and been dying.

If you want to continue your program, just catch exception;

```
...
catch (const char *)
{
    cout << "Unhandled exception!" << endl;
    // continue......
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. `set_terminate` allows you to provide a callback to run at program exit, not *instead of* program exit.

Also, you threw `const char*` (sort of) but tried to catch `int`, which is why your exception was not handled. Simply catch it properly.

Comment: int is there just for the sake of example.